# OpenGL Java -- Bulk creation of VBOs

Tags: java, opengl

I have been following [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/OpenGL) tutorial for OpenGL, porting it into java from their C++ as best I can but it prompted me to wonder what the best way of mass-producing VBOs is. The tutorial says to use VAOs to store VBOs for later use, however the LWJGL forums say that VAOs are deprecated in favor of simply using many, many VBOs or making just a few, then reusing them.

In either case, how would be the best way to implement this? Should I create each one all at once, in one class? Or should I make java classes to automate and abstract that work further? If I am needing make many, many VBOs, surely that extra layer would add considerable lag?

Either way, any advice is appreciated! I am new to OpenGL, however have a pretty good grip on its workings -- just not how to actually use them!

Ps.: I have no specific requirements for OpenGL version. Currently I am using 3.3, but if another version is optimal, then I would happily switch.

Comment: "Best way" tends to be opinion based.  As is, I see no code and the answer is likely to depend a lot on your code.  Any of those ideas you list could be a reasonable implementation, given a specific code architecture.

Comment: Could you link to the place where it states that VAOs are deprecated? In modern GL (3.3 core +), you cannot at all draw without using a VAO. It also seems that there is a slight misunderstanding of what VAOs do: VAOs only store state, not data. They only store which VBO is bound, but they do not store the VBO itself.

Comment: Haven't been able to find the thread, but whoever posted it evidently had outdated information. The thread _was_ quite old.